# Plutus: Integer->Value?

Tags: plutus, smart-contract

I give to Integer via an endpoint function, multiply them and give them to
`Constraints.mustPayToTheScript`. For this I need the result to be converted into an `Value`. Does Anyone know how to do this?

```
 buy =  endpoint @"buy" @BuyParams $ \ (BuyParams fst scd ) -> do
    let amt = fst*scd
    let tx         = Constraints.mustPayToTheScript (hashString fst) amt
    void (submitTxConstraints gameInstance tx)
```

Comment: Is ADA what you want to pay to the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing that you want to pay **ADA** to the script, you can use `lovelaceValueOf :: Integer -> Value` from `Plutus.V1.Ledger.Ada` as follows:

```
import qualified Plutus.V1.Ledger.Ada as Ada

buy = endpoint @"buy" @BuyParams $ \ (BuyParams fst scd ) -> do
   let amt = fst*scd
       val = Ada.lovelaceValueOf amt
       tx  = Constraints.mustPayToTheScript (hashString fst) val
   void (submitTxConstraints gameInstance tx)
```

[image]

Hope this will be useful.

Comment: Yes! Solved it thanks :)

Comment: @John_Bones more than welcome!